# Using .env constants with Laravel Mix and React

Tags: laravel, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, laravel-mix

I'm trying to integrate an existing React project with Laravel. I'm using Laravel Mix to compile the assets.

I managed to get everything going, besides one thing: I do not know how to make Mix read constants from the .env file, which are needed for the Webpack build process.

I'm using Firebase, and the various keys are kept in this .env file. Of course i could work around it, but i would like to make it properly.

I do not see anything in the webpack.mix.js file that implies this functionality. How can it be done?

Comment: You could try `const APP_NAME = process.env.APP_NAME || 'Laravel'`

Further reading: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Answer (score 4):

You can prefix your keys with `MIX_` and access them via `process.env` once you recompile your js.

So having `mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js');` or `mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js');` will work fine.

You will also need to restart any running watch tasks for changes to take effect.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1096#issuecomment-320328087

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#environment-variables

Comment: I just want to stress that restarting any running watch tasks is really important -- this took me hours to solve a missing env URL until I bumped into your solution. NPM run watch appears to be observing changes on your app except for the .env file. Thank you!